# Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'gvStoreInventry'. Remove one definition

Tags: asp.net, ado.net

Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'gvStoreInventry'. Remove one definition.
I am not able to detect the Error. Please help

```
protected void btnShowData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
            {
                SqlCommand cmdShowData = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblStoreInventory", con);
                con.Open();
                gvStoreInventry.DataSource = cmdShowData.ExecuteReader();
                gvStoreInventry.DataBind();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `DataSourceID` on the element if you want to set it manually on the code behind.

```
<asp:TheUserControl ID="gvStoreInventry" runat="server" 
     DataSourceID="TheDataSourceID" />
          <!-- ^^^^^^ -->
       <!-- Remove This -->
</asp:TheUserControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to aspx Designer
select **gvStoreInventry**

hit **f4**--> 
Proporty pane Should Popout

Arrange property pane **a-z** wize from top of Proporty pane A-Z link.

Look for **DatasourceID**-->
 if there is some thing please blank the filled